# create a user in AD with full permission in her pc but connect to Remote Desktop with permission limited

Tags: permissions, active-directory, account

I want to create a user in  Active Directory with full permission (install or delete an application).

But the user need to a server to do . With this same user, I want her pc to connect to the server using Remote Desktop with permission limited (cant dowload an app, delete etc..)

It's possible ?

Hope u will help me.

Upadate solution : Put a GPO on the Remote Desktop with  permission limited ang user group

Thx,
Pinki

Comment: User permissions are mainly managed using group policies. Explore the same in `gpmc.msc`!

Comment: Yeah I know that i should user group policies but don't know exactly if i should change permissions on the server or on the users who can access to the server. And if i do, which permissions should i change / add /accord ?

Comment: You should change the policy on the AD server, in one of the policies (either existing default group policy, not recommended, or create a new one, and add the user to that policy's scope). For example, you can restrict admin access on her ID which will disable her from installing app, but downloading would work most likely.